# What does "every mutating transaction must be performed in a transaction" mean with respect to databases?

Tags: database, transactions, neo4j

Found this while reading the Neo4j manual, specifically [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html), I found the sentence:

"All mutating transactions have to be performed in a transaction."

Clearly a mutating transaction isn't just a type of transaction of the latter sort. Could someone help clarify the relationship between each of these things and the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should say all mutating *operations* should be performed inside a transaction. A mutating operation is stuff like creating or updating a node/relationship, or adding stuff to an index.

If you are using the Java API directly (i.e. not the REST API), then you must wrap each create or update method in a transaction.

Here's an example of creating and indexing a node, wrapped in a transaction:

https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/neo4jserver/gremlin.groovy#L11

Note that the code above is the Neo4j Java API, but it's being used in a Groovy script.

You can execute Groovy scripts via the Neo4j Server Gremlin-Groovy Plugin. This means you have access to the entire Neo4j Java API via REST.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a minor typo, better read as the title of that section:

> Wrap mutating operations in a transaction

Here operations mean any access to the model that modifies the model (e.g. adding new nodes or relationships in the example linked).  To maintain consistency in the database you wrap these modifying operations in a transaction so either all succeed or non, avoiding leaving the database in an inconsistent state

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing it up, updated the wording, see https://github.com/neo4j/community/commit/ba94448d495e6d9fec8877bd32bd5edf0936b621

Is that better?